# Bind10 transfer zone when modifying 'records' table

Tags: dns

When I add a new column to the default table 'records',

ALTER TABLE records ADD COLUMN info_col TEXT;

The zone can transfer from Master to Slave but all the informations of column 'info_col' cannot be transferred to Slave.

I follow this guide to configure Master-Slave:
http://www.tokiwinter.com/bind-10-zone-transfers-tsig-and-ddns/

Is there any way to transfer the information of 'info_col' with zone?

Please help!

Thanks in advance,